# client.run(TOKEN) command blocks other blocs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

i wrote a program like this

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    user = await client.fetch_user(ID)
    await DMChannel.send(user, plus)
client.run(TOKEN)
print("Okay")
```

but

```
print("Okay")
```

command doesnt work.
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

`client.run(TOKEN)` stops the code at that point. Any code underneath it will run only after the bot has been shutdown. Put any code that you want to run immediately above `client.run(TOKEN)`

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the mechanics of how does asyncio works. In the nutshell, asyncio creates a loop, which is a **blocking code** meaning that nothing outside of it won't run until loop finishes, and inside of that loop asyncio makes coroutines work asynchronous, that just how architecture works, nothing to do about it.

`Client.run()` actually runs bot's asyncio loop and that's why nothing after that command works (at least until the point when you stop your bot).

To make your commands work you have to put them before calling `Client.run()` or which is better in my view - to add them into the loop by calling `Client.loop.create_task(your async function)`. Take into account, that function you pass into the `create_task` should be without brackets and that **must** be an async function.

And yes, you should call `create_task` before running the loop, or from the loop itself.